# Smarty and Bootstrap JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, smarty

I wrote a PHP page with Smarty template engine and decided to use Bootstrap UI in my project. 
CSS works fine, but JavaScript doesn't work. I tried to use that without Smarty = all works excellent.

For example, hint:

index.tpl:

```
{config_load file="$tolangpath"} 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
<title>{#HomePageTitle#}</title> 
{include file='libs.tpl'} 
</head> 
<body class="metro" style="background:url('./templates/images/bg-index.png') no-repeat;background-size:100%;"> 

<div style="text-align:right;padding-right:15px;"> 
<a href="#" 
    data-hint="Title|This is a hint for Me" 
    data-hint-position="top"> 
        Hover me... 
</a> 

</div> 
<div class="example" style="margin-left:35%;margin-top:10%;width:400px;"> 
                                <form action="./include/process/login.php"> 
                                    <fieldset> 
                                        <img src="./templates/images/logo.png" align="center"> 
                                        <label>{#Login#}</label> 
                                        <div class="input-control text" data-role="input-control"> 
                                            <input name="login" type="text" placeholder="{#LoginInput#}"> 
                                            <button tabindex="-1" class="btn-clear" type="button"></button> 
                                        </div> 
                                        <label>{#Password#}</label> 
                                        <div class="input-control password" data-role="input-control"> 
                                            <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="{#PasswordInput#}"> 
                                            <button tabindex="-1" class="btn-reveal" type="button"></button> 
                                        </div> 
                                        <div class="input-control checkbox" data-role="input-control"> 
                                            <label> 
                                                <input type="checkbox" checked=""> 
                                                <span class="check"></span> 
                                                {#RememberMe#} 
                                            </label> 
                                        </div> 
                              <br> 
                                        <input type="submit" value="{#LoginButton#}"> 
                              <a class="button primary" href="./register" data-pjax="#main">{#RegisterButton#}</a> 
                              <a class="button default" href="./recover">{#ForgotPassword#}</a> 
                                    </fieldset> 
                                </form> 
                            </div> 
</body> 
</html>
 `</code>
```

libs.tpl:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./templates/css/metro-bootstrap.css"> 
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="./templates/css/passProtect.css"> 
              <script src="./templates/js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script> 
            <script src="./templates/js/passProtect.js"></script> 
        <script src="./templates/js/jquery.widget.min.js"></script> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="./templates/js/metro.min.js"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./templates/js/jquery.pjax.js"></script>
```

Pjax (https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax) doesn't work too.

Comment: console logs?  What 'doesn't work'

Comment: Smarty uses { and } for delimiters by default. In javascript these characters are common. Sometimes this can cause problems. But I don't see any of them in your example...

Comment: How does the generated html look?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'split' metro-hint.js:35
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'stop' of undefined